# How do I create an int list of Hex numbers dynamically including "0x" prefix?

Tags: flutter, dart, hex

I have a list as follows:

```
final List<int> timeSync = [
  0x24,
  0x0e,
  0x07
]
```

This list above is manually created. All numbers are hex and have a "0x" prefix. This is accepted as an int list and does not give an error when passed to a function that accepts an int list.

Now, I have another list of decimal integers:

```
final List<int> nums = [
  13,
  45,
  09
]
```

I want the list "nums" to be converted into an int list of hexes (like the manually created one above, with the "0x" prefix).

I have tried converting the int into hex by using `toRadixString()` function and prepending the results with "0x". But that converts it into a string, which is unacceptable.

All help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert List of int to List of hex:
use `int.toRadixString(16)`

Your list

```
final List<int> nums = [
  13,
  45,
  09
];
```

this is how to convert it :

```
List convertedNum = nums.map((num) =>  num.toRadixString(16)).toList();
```